# Increase table size in invoice package

Tags: invoice

I am using the `invoice` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/invoice) but the resulting fee table is only 70% of the page in width. Furthermore, the first row, the description, is very small.

How can I increase the table size?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[german,comma]{invoice}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}


        \begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}
            \ProjectTitle{IT Random Consulting} %
            \Fee{Integration Diesdas Aktienanalysen}{100}{1}
        \end{invoice}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain your problem further by providing a complete and compilable minimal working example.

Comment: The `invoice` environment uses a `longtable` with specification `p{5cm}lrrr`. The 5cm is hardwired.

Comment: if your comment about row refers to colum then by design " The contents of each fee may be verbose; while the column width is
limited, text contents longer than the column width wraps over several columns, [sic I think that should be rows]
if necessary."

Comment: And there is no way to overwrite the longtable specification?

Comment: you could try invoice2 as default margins are thiner HOWEVER without line wrap long lines will simply go out off the page through the right hand margin !! ~~So sticking with Invoice and getting someone to suggest mods to margins may be simpler @egreg has point out the column variable perhaps he can guide/answer you on shifting the margin width and how to alter 5cm to say 7cm ?

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite the `longtable` specification you can use package `etoolbox` and command `\patchcmd` like (`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed because the code uses an `@`):

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\my@invoice}%
  {\begin{longtable}{p{5cm}lrrr}}%
  {\begin{longtable}{p{9cm}lrrr}}% <========================================
  {}{} % success failure
\makeatother
```

With the complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[%
  top=2cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm,
  showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[german,comma]{invoice}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \patchcmd

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\my@invoice}%
  {\begin{longtable}{p{5cm}lrrr}}%
  {\begin{longtable}{p{9cm}lrrr}}% <========================================
  {}{} % success failure
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}
  \ProjectTitle{IT Random Consulting} %
  \Fee{Integration Diesdas Aktienanalysen}{100}{1}
\end{invoice}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please sse that I used package option `showframe` to visualize the used typing area and margins ...

Comment: +1 for a neat solution

Answer (score 0):

As stated by egreg the feature of invoice causing you issues is hard coded and you would either need to amend the .sty (which would at least require you to copy files to local texmf then renaming and editing) which could cause further support issues. OR amend it on the fly as mentioned in the other answer.

An alternative is to use a different modifiable invoice package if it's suited to your needs

There are several that you should be able to use without modification other than shown in the documentation. There is **NO need to download** from CTAN since they should be **installable from your package manager**.

The two I think likely to suite your case are found [here](https://ctan.org/topic/invoice) (simply read each documentation PDF)

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/isodoc/isodoc.pdf
http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/simpleinvoice/doc/simpleinvoice.pdf

do check the overview of the others in case I am wrong https://ctan.org/topic/invoice